# .NET 6 docker container with watch

Tags: .net, docker

How do I create a docker container that will run .NET with hot reload via `dotnet watch run`? Most of the solutions online go the right way but there is always something wrong like:

- container starts fine but the port is not the one I specify and port forwarding directives dont work
- container cannot be built because of `"watch" is not something dotnet can run`
- project files cannot be found or copied
  and many others that I forgot to mention but encountered on my way to the solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all run `dotnet new webapi -o YOURPROJECTNAME` to setup the development environment with a mock api controller.

Then place this docker-compose.yml file in your root:

```yaml
version: "3.4"

services:
  app:
    image: YOURIMAGENAME
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    depends_on:
      - db
```

Then add this Dockerfile:

```sh
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0-focal

WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app
RUN dotnet restore

ENTRYPOINT [ "dotnet", "watch", "run", "--no-restore", "--urls", "http://*:8080" ]
```

Then add this .dockerignore:

```
bin
obj
```

After all this is done run `docker-compose up` to run the container and voila, have fun developing APIs with .NET in a container with hot reload!